# xamarin.ios build just get stucked after i updated my vs15 to vs17

Tags: debugging, xamarin.ios, slowdown

i updated vs to VS17from vs15. now I  cant build my xamarin.ios project
its just stuck and loading from more than half hour.

please help me if anyone have found same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me, you can try and check.

Delete all data from here then restart `vs` and try clean and rebuild.

```
C:\Users\currentuser\AppData\Local\Xamarin
```